# Linux uninstalled on its own?

Tags: linux, pop-os

I have been using the linux for almost 2.5 years. I wanted to reinstall as I want to upgrade to some other linux distro. I dual booted linux with windows around 20 days back. I made a bootable pendrive and installed it. I had made separate partitions for my linux including root, home, boot and swap. It was working completely fine until I plugged in my bootable pendrive again. I booted into linux and I want to use it as a normal pendrive thats why I formatted it. After formatting the pendrive, I used my linux for about 6-7 hours and forgot to remove the pendrive. Next day, when I turned on my pc it was gone. Whole linux is gone. Earlier, I thought that there might be some bug but when I booted into Windows and checked the partitions, all partitions which I assigned for my linux were empty. I know it sounds weird but even I am confused. I am pretty sure that for formatting I chose my pendrive partition and not any other linux partition. Is it even possible? Is it because I plugged in a linux bootable pendrive?
Someone please help me understand what has happened.
Thank You

EDIT--------
I again made a bootable pendrive and tried installing pop os. When I checked the partitions while installing, all my partitions and my data is still there. I dont know why in Windows it is showing them 100% free. So I have all my data including all the installed packages but the issue is how to access them. How can I boot into my linux? In boot menu and in bios, it is nowhere showing my linux. Can someone please help
Thank you

Comment: Windows can't read native Linux partitions, so to Windows they appear "empty"... it sounds like Windows updated and over-wrote grub (the bootloader) which meant you couldn't access your Linux installation, but it was there. This is not uncommon when Windows updates occur. The correct fix is usually just boot the install media for your Linux distribution and use it's boot repair tool (if one is available, most Ubuntu derivatives have it), or check it's support forums for how to do it manually.

Comment: Are you sure you formatted pen drive? If I reboot with a flash drive plugged in, it becomes sda & every other drive up one letter. Or I have to pay attention to which drive is which if using any command based on /dev/xxx.

Comment: Thank you for the support. Since I was using Pop!_OS, I found out a solution on the official website. There was an issue with my bootloader, I had to mount up all my partitions and reinstall the kerne in the recovery model. http://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/